# Print chunks form a list

Tags: python, list

How can I print chunks of size 5 from a list and the remaining tail end that does not have chunk size of 5

For example

```
a = list(range(23))
```

I want to produce print out

```
[0,1,2,3,4], [5,6,7,8,9], [10,11,12,13,14], [15,16,17,18,19], [20,21,22]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

from the [itertools recipes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes):

```
from functools import partial
from itertools import islice

def take(n, iterable):
    return tuple(islice(iterable, n))

def chunked(iterable, n):
    return iter(partial(take, n, iter(iterable)), tuple())

a = list(range(23))
print(list(chunked(a, 5)))
# [(0, 1, 2, 3, 4), (5, 6, 7, 8, 9), (10, 11, 12, 13, 14), 
#  (15, 16, 17, 18, 19), (20, 21, 22)]
```

or simply:

```
n = 5
[a[j:j+n] for j in range(0, len(a), n)]
```

Comment: does `chunked` need the two `iter` calls? If yes, why?

Comment: yes, you need to have a fresh iterator to pass to `take`.

Comment: @Ev.Kounis I think the question relates to the inner `iter` in `iter(iterable)`. That one is necessary to turn e.g. sequences into *lazy* iterators that can be exhausted.